# Docker volume data does not get saved to host folder in mac

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, docker-compose

Here is my docker compose file

```
version "2"
services:
    my_postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        volumes:
          - /Users/my_user_name/test_docker/my_volume_space:/var/lib/postgresql
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
```

I entered the following command in mac

```
docker-machine start
docker-machine env
evcal "$(docker-machine env default)"

docker-compose up

psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 5432 -U postgres

create table test (my_id bigserial primary key);
INSERT INTO test (my_id) values (1);
SELECT * FROM test;

\q
```

Originally I thought the above commands will cause a `.sql` file to be created in `./my_volume_space` of the host computer. But I don't see any `.sql` file in `./my_volume_space` rather just an empty `data` directory in `./my_volume_space`

Furthermore if I `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` again I can see my data in the database is now gone.

I suspected that when I created the data when the image is running, the data is not stored back to `./my_volume_space` thus when I reboot, there is nothing to mount from the host.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if "sync" works for example by attaching into my_postgres container and doing something like "touch /var/lib/postgresql/testfile.txt" ? If it appears in your host then maybe this image keeps pg data somewhere else, or it didn't somplete the sync yet since docker volume mounting on mac is really slow using osxfs. I even made article about this: espeo.eu/blog/docker-for-mac-performance-tweaks/

Answer (score 1):

Path volumes do not work on docker-machine (macOS) with postgres image, [source](https://forums.docker.com/t/initdb-could-not-create-directory-var-lib-postgresql-data-pg-xlog-permission-denied/7813).

The work-around is to use named volumes. Example docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  test-postgres-compose :
    ...
    volumes :
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
...
volumes :
  pgdata :
```

[Docker compose volumes info](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the volume path on the container is to `/var/lib/postgresql/data` not `/var/lib/postgresql`